# How to decrypt,encrypted data using Cryptography

Tags: c#

Hello i'm trying to make a simple encrypt,decrypt algorithm and i maked encrypt code correctly,but description code not working

```
    static string Encript(string value)
    {
        using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
            byte[] data = md5.ComputeHash(utf8.GetBytes(value));
            return Convert.ToBase64String(data);
        }
    }

    static string Decript(string value)
    {
        using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider Tdecript = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider())
        {

             UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
             byte[] DataToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
             return utf8.GetString(DataToDecrypt);
        }
    }
```

[this is show when i press decript button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXmfU.png)

Comment: this is the error shows nothing?

Comment: @Thomas sorry i fix it

Comment: You are aware that hashing is a one-way function right? You can't decrypt hashes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encrypt and decrypt a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202011/encrypt-and-decrypt-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

First of all you are using a [Hash Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) to "encrypt" your data. Hashing is a one way function. Thus you will not be able to "decrypt" your data.

Second of all: MD5 is not a good hashing mechanism. Please use something like SHA256.

Third: To encrypt + decrypt I would recommend you to use AES256.

Here is a sample on how to achieve this:

[AESManaged Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

This may not answer you original question **but do not use MD5** - it is considered broken. I would use sha-256 as a minimum if you actually want to keep the information you are hashing secure.

To answer you question

To my knowledge the MD5 hash you are using is a one way function - meaning you take a password and hash it, stick it in a db - when a user comes back you do not decrypt the data and check the two values match but you create a new hash of the data they gave you and compare these two.

If you need a two way encryption service I would look at AES.

Comment: This repeats the other answer..

Comment: It does because that is the answer to the question - at the time of writing no other answer was present on this question.

Comment: The other answer was written nine minutes before yours was.

Comment: posted not written, I took my time answering a question that had no reply's at the time - once posted others had got there before me. Its really not a big deal.